# Can I get rid of an unwanted acronym?

Tags: keyboard, languages

Apparently "ESCO" is an acronym for something, however "esco" is a quite common Italian word. For some reason the native keyboard seems to prefer the acronym to the word, usually having it as default, and sometimes not even giving the word as an alternative.

Can I either remove the acronym, or at least force the word to have more priority?

(system is CM 10.2.1, Android 4.3.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Language & input -> Personal dictionary and add "esco". If "ESCO" is present, remove it.